# Can I transfer airside between two international tickets at LAX?

Tags: usa, transit, covid-19, south-africa

I am traveling from South Africa to Sydney. My first flight is from South Africa to Los Angeles via Dubai on Emirates.

After nine hours I have a second separate ticket departing to Sydney, Australia on Delta Airlines.

Although I have both Pfizer shots, I understand that entry into USA is still not allowed, but transit is allowed within 24 hours. Can this interconnection with two tickets work, assuming I transit ONLY airside with no checked luggage from Emirates to Delta?

I do have a USA visa and Australian regulatory approval to enter Sydney so the main issue is the no entry into USA landside currently in place.

Comment: "but transit is allowed within 24hours" source?

Comment: LAX is in the USA (as far as I know the codes) and the USA does not do 'transit area only' transits, only transits in which you enter the country and then next leave the country.

Comment: I think you've got some bad information.  The US doesn't have airside transit at all; you always have to enter the country, no matter how short your transit is.  And the [entry ban for South Africa](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/presidential-actions/2021/01/25/proclamation-on-the-suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-non-immigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of-transmitting-coronavirus-disease/) has no exceptions for travelers in transit.  So your "transit is allowed within 24 hours" doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: This is also a quite complicated route, if you don't need to go to LA specifically - SA > Dubai > Australia would save a day or more in transit time and avoid the whole US layover issue.

Comment: @Andrew if normal times that would most definitely make sense. But these days flights to Australia are extremely limited, and it’s nearly impossible to get a flight from DXB to SYD, do people need to be “creative”. This route doesn’t work, though.

Comment: @jcaron aha - I had assumed the limiting factor was being allowed in rather than the actual seat on the plane! But I guess it makes sense both are in short supply.

Comment: That's one heck of a detour: almost 20,000 miles

Comment: Your itinerary might make sense on this kind of [map](https://www.freeworldmaps.net/world/america-centric/america-centered-world-map.jpg), but as seen on a globe, its completely ridiculous.

Comment: Maybe you should restate your question. The real problem you are trying to solve is how to get from South Africa to Australia.

Comment: You can't fly from SA to Australia over the south pole?

Comment: The South Pole [is a bit of a detour from the Johannesburg-to-Sydney route](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=JNB-SYD).

Comment: @EricDuminil True, but if the only flight to Australia you can find is from LAX, the problem reduces to "how do I get to LAX from ZA" and for that the proposed route is fairly sane. (Of course, it is only sane when ignoring the main issue of being allowed into the US in the first place.)

Comment: @TooTea Well. "Not flying" is always a perfectly fine alternative.

Comment: @EricDuminil Sure, but I assume that anyone contemplating a round-the-world itinerary like this just to get from A to B has an _extremely compelling_ reason to travel.

Comment: @JulianSortland Even before Covid, JNB-SYD flights were a bit of a rarity and a quite recent addition IIRC. With the extreme restrictions on international travel to Australia (including reasons for travel, mandatory hotel quarantine, **extremely** limited quotas per airline...) flights to Australia have been a lot more limited (there are less than a dozen international arrivals in SYD each day!), and most routes have been discontinued. At this time, the next available flight from JNB to SYD is November 14th (via Addis Ababa and Bangkok), taking 54 hours. A detour via LAX does not seem to bad!

Comment: Correction: there's a flight on November 4th, via Nairobi, Abu Dhabi and Melbourne, for a very cheap €21696!

Comment: Additional, unless you are an Australia Citizen or have special approval (extremely difficult to get) you will not be allowed enter Australia at this time. And even if you can, it'll involve 2 weeks in quarantine at your expense.

Comment: @Doc OP wrote they have "Australian regulatory approval to enter Sydney", is that the same thing?

Answer (score 37):

I'm afraid that the answer is, at this time, clearly, resolutely, and absolutely, **no**.

There are **no exceptions for transit to the current travel bans**, whatever the duration of transit.

There is **no airside transit in any airport in the US**. All passengers, whatever their final destination, will go through immigration (passport/visa control), reclaim their luggage, if any, and go through customs, before they can move on. In the vast majority of cases (and that includes LAX), passengers will end up landside in the public area, before they go to departures and then go through security to go back airside.

Even if the two flights were on the same ticket, you would not be allowed to board a flight to the US if you have been in any of the banned countries in the last 14 days and you are not an exempt person (US citizen or permanent resident and a few other similar exceptions).

Even if there was an exception for transit (which doesn’t exist), with flights on separate tickets, the first airline would consider your final destination to be the US, and again, you would not be allowed to board.

There is talk about lifting restrictions for some countries, but I have no idea if South Africa is supposed to be part of those changes, there is still no date ("early November" is all we have)ù, and no details.

Comment: It probably won't help OP due to COVID restrictions, but it's maybe worth noting that under specific circumstances (right airport, right gates) airside transit is possible in *Canada*, even though it's never possible in the US.

Answer (score 1):

I have done several international arrivals at LAX.  The sequence of events is:

Immigration.

Baggage claim.

Customs.

The exit from customs will be **ground**side--it has to be, because there are items permitted in checked baggage that are not permitted airside.

Some airports have a setup right as you exit customs for connecting passengers--a baggage conveyor right there that if your bag is properly tagged you can just drop it on the belt rather than go to the check-in counter.  Those belts are groundside, though.

Furthermore, US international departure gates are not isolated.  I have walked from an international departure gate to outside any building (although still on airport grounds) without encountering any barriers at all.  I then returned to the gate without encountering anything more than normal airport security.  There is no outgoing border control in the US.  (8 hour mechanical delay, I didn't like the food choices within the area I could access airside.)